# How to calculate $\lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\int _0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^tdt}{\sqrt{x^3}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> $$ \lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\int _0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^tdt}{\sqrt{x^3}} $$

I tried to use mean value theorem

> $$ \int _0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^tdt = \sqrt{x-\xi}e^\xi \cdot x, \xi \in (0,x)$$

but i don't know how to continue

> $$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{x-\xi}e^\xi \cdot x}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

I tried use l'Hopital

> $$ \left(\int _0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^tdt \right)' = \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{x-t}}dt. $$

Is there exists an solution about using mean value theorem?

Comment: Hint: you could use l'Hopital and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: @MarioGonzalez I tried , but the derivative of the  $\int _0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^tdt$ is also complex.

Comment: The trick is to use the $y=a+b-y$ property and then differentiate. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x \sqrt{x-t} e^t \ \mathrm{d}t &= \int_0^x \sqrt{t}e^{x-t} \ \mathrm{d}t && \text{by Border Flip}\\
&= e^x \int_0^x \sqrt{t}e^{-t} \ \mathrm{d}t\\
\implies \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\int_0^x \sqrt{x-t} e^t \ \mathrm{d}t}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}} &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^x \int_0^x \sqrt{t} e^{-t} \ \mathrm{d}t}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
&= \left ( \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^x \right ) \left ( \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-x} x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}} \right ) && \text{by L'H}\hat{\mathrm{o}}\text{pital's Rule}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2}{3} e^{-x}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: You may take the limit on $e^{-x}$ before applying L'hopital Rule, simplifying the derivation

Comment: @Jorge Thanks for the simplification!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer using Leibniz's and L'Hopital's rule:

$$L= \lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\bigg(\int _0^x\sqrt{t}e^{x-t}dt\bigg)'}{\bigg(\sqrt{x^3}\bigg)'}= \lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\sqrt x+\int _0^x\frac{\partial e^{x-t}}{\partial x}\sqrt tdt}{\frac32\sqrt{x}}=\lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\sqrt x+\int _0^xe^{x-t}\sqrt tdt}{\frac32\sqrt{x}}=\lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\bigg(\sqrt x+\int _0^xe^{x-t}\sqrt tdt\bigg)'}{\bigg(\frac32\sqrt{x}\bigg)'}=\lim _{x\to 0+} \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}+\int _0^xe^{x-t}\sqrt tdt}{\frac{3}{4\sqrt x}}=\frac23$$

Comment: use \partial not \delta

Comment: @DavidP noted!!

Answer (score 2):

Although I like Sharky Kesa's answer more, I will provide an alternative answer that do not use FTC or L'hopital Rule. We,ll solve this limit using a change of variable and squeeze limit. Let $t=xu \Rightarrow dt=xdu$. Then
\begin{gather*}
\int_0^x\sqrt{x-t}e^{t}dt = \int_0^1\sqrt{x-xu}e^{xu}xdu = x^{\frac{3}{2}}\int_0^1\sqrt{1-u}e^{xu}du
\end{gather*}
so our limit becomes
\begin{gather*}
L =\lim_{x \to 0^+} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}e^{xu}du
\end{gather*}
Now, notice that
\begin{gather*}
0 \leq xu \leq x \Rightarrow e^0=1\leq e^{xu} \leq e^x
\end{gather*}
Now, applying integral monotonicity
\begin{gather*}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}du \leq \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}e^{xu}du \leq e^x \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}du
\end{gather*}
Finally, applying squeeze limit we get
\begin{gather*}
L = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}e^{xu}du = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u}du = \frac{2}{3}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Thats great solution!